# Simulating shell command in JAVA

Tags: java, android

If I run the command `adb shell cat /dev/input/event0` at command prompt, it shows some raw data corresponding to user actions on Android emulator.

I want to simulate this command programmatically with Java to record user actions.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

command is a string you pass.
```